# Importing schemas from phpmyadmin to mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I had created a schema on xampp (phpmyadmin) which is running on port 3306. I later installed Mysql separately on port 3307. When I open mysql running on port 3307, and open it on 3306, it automatically imported the schema s on phpmyadmin into it. but later after I shutdown and restart the machine, neither phpmyadmin nor mysql is allowed to run on 3306. mysql is running on 3307 when i try to run it on 3306 it gives error 2003. Firewall hasnt blocked it either. how can i make either of it run?

Comment: What have you setup in your mysql.ini? If you have specified a port number, or specified --skip-networking then read this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-connecting.html

Comment: I did change the port in my.ini file. but doesnt work. the machine requests permission to make changes to the computer and the program name it ives is "net command".